# How long does raw ground meat last in the fridge?

Tags: food-safety, meat, storage-lifetime

Does it make a difference if it's raw ground pork or raw ground veal?  There is no sell-by date since I got it at the butcher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's raw, stick with the best-before date on the label.  If cooked, you have at least [3-4 days](http://www.stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/18065), regardless of whether it's pork, veal, or regular beef.

Answer (score 1):

The store kept it at 30°F (-1°C) or less, at least in the US. Since your fridge is probably warmer, you probably want to use (or freeze) within two or three days, regardless of the sell-by date.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your refrigerator (Europe has them at +4 Celcius) your meat should last no longer than 3-4 days. This assuming it did not spend more days in the butchers' fridge before being given to you.

Remember tho -- your nose is *always* the best teller. You will know if it smells funny instinctively; and een if you eat meat that is not 100% fresh, you might as well feel sick for a day or so, and learn the lesson for the next time. We evolved along with our sense of smell, and if we are still here there is a reason* :)

*simply put, those who had a decent sense of smell survived and had childrens

Comment: Your nose cannot detect bacterial contamination, only rancidity. Don't follow this advice.

Answer (score 0):

Three days is pushing it, in my opinion.  Best use on the second day.